# Create SKView programmatically?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I like my code to be explicit so I want to remove the `storyboard` file and create `SKView` programmatically.

What I have tried so far:

1. I created a `SpriteKit` game project in *xcode*.
2. Deleted the storyboard file.
3. Deleted sroryboard property from `Info.plist`
4. Added this code found in an example to the `AppDelegate`:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       AppViewController *viewController = [[AppViewController alloc] init];
       viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
       _window.rootViewController = viewController;
       [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
   }
   ```
5. Added this code to the `AppViewController`:

   ```
   -(void) loadView
   {
       self.view = [[SKView alloc] init];
   }
   ```

The app starts but then crashes on the creation of first sprite with the following warning

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I think there should be some good examples of how to do this, but I have not found any for the `SpriteKit` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by setting a frame to the view:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    self.view = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

Here is a [working example project in Swift](https://github.com/dimklo/ProgrammaticViewExample/tree/master/ProgrammaticViewExample)

Comment: how do you do this in Swift? I'm trying `view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds` but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I have not tried it as my project is in Obj-c, but the Swift equivalent should be: self.view = SKView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

Comment: I've already got the SKView, so don't get a chance to init it. It doesn't work. I'm trying to do a SK project from scratch, starting from no code, to understand it. But I give up, for now. Back to the template. *groan*

Comment: This is the exact purpose of overriding the loadView method - to allow you to create SKView programmatically.

Comment: Could you write like you're talking to an idiot, and explain it a bit more fully?

Comment: I added a link to a working example project to my answer

Comment: This moron thanks you greatly! I'll digest and come back with more idiotic and stupid questions. Probably about frames and bounds.