# How to set root view controller programmatically in Xcode 13 with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In the SpriteKit starting template of Xcode 12, there is no `SceneDelegate` file, so instructions for UIKit applications do not work. After I delete the `Main.storyboard` and the `info.plist` entry, I get a black screen. Here's the `AppDelegate` for the SpriteKit template in Xcode 12:

```swift
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    } 
}
```

As I understand, we need to integrate GameScene here, instead of the SceneDelegate, but trying to type-cast it like `guard let winScene = (scene as? SKScene) else { return }` understandably does not work, since the `application` function is different.

How to proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: I got it working the way you want it using this answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659415/create-skview-programmatically.

Comment: But I would just leave the Main.storyboard as it is and start adding nodes programmatically into the Gamescene.swift

Comment: @StefanOvomate Thank you for the quick answer. Example project works fine after converting it to Swift 5, but new projects from Xcode 12 do not comply :\. I think I'll leave it as is I guess.

Comment: I just tested it in Xcode 12. Everything is working fine.

Comment: AH yes. I was trying it out directly on existing project, and I got a black screen due to an unrelated thing. All good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the Main.Storyboard, you need to add the following to your AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
     window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     let viewController = GameViewController()
     window?.rootViewController = viewController
     window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

And in GameViewController.swift you need to add the following:

```
    override func loadView() {
       self.view = SKView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }
```